# synching a contact edit across various Google accounts & Samsung account

Tags: contacts, sync, google-account, google-contacts

this may be a familiar situation with many  
.
you may have multiple google accounts and one propriety phone provider account e.g. Samsung account

exemplifying the above

g1 - Google account 1

g2 - Google account 2

s1 - Samsung account  
so  when a contact is added  it may reside in g1 & s1 or g1 or  g2  &  s1
if I edit the contact in g1 , the edit will not show up everywhere including WhatsApp unless and until I edit the very same contact with exactly the same update,   on g2  &  s1 manually.  
what I would like to do is if I edit contact in g1 , the same number in g2 and s1 should automatically get the cascading edit.  
how do I achieve this ?

Comment: Not possible AFAIK, both are separate containers synced to separate servers and there is no interface that is possible, unless you manually export contacts from one and sync into other and keep doing it periodically

Comment: how about between Google accounts forget the propriety

Comment: Again not possible, separate accounts have everything separate contacts, mail, drive etc

Comment: understand cm'ly is there any playstore app that will do that

Comment: Not that I am aware of

Comment: I guess so.... another one I thought might interest you.                               https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/242902/cold-blooded-hotspot-frequent-internet-connection-failures-why-do-they

Comment: Sorry, but that's beyond me!

Comment: No issues ...   thanks & much appr'd your earlier replies.