# "cold Blooded" hotspot : frequent internet connection failures. ... why do they happen

Tags: root-access, connection-issues, wifi-hotspot, system-apps, dalvik

**Short Story shorter**  
`Hotspot`  denies internet access to  `Puppy Linux` client only on a specific laptop while all other clients have no issue ( the same laptop with Windows partition can connect without any issue     ) and the only way I could fix it is "reset network settings" + reboot. Nothing else seems to work.

**Scenario** 
2 Mobile phones : 1 Culprit Xiaomi  H1  and 1 AT & T ( control ) H2
Here is the picture cheat sheeted

```
normal laptop NL
Problem laptop PL

Problem hotspot # 1 H1
Ok hotspot # 2 - H2
puppy refers to the puppy Linux partition on the laptop
so e.g. PL.Puppy  ❌   H1 means puppy Linux on PL aka 
problem laptop does not have internet connection via 
hotspot H1

PL.Puppy  ❌   H1
PL.Puppy  ✓   H2
PL.WIndows ✓ H1
NL            ✓  H 1 && H2
 
I am able to ping the gateway 192.168.43.1 & traceroute 
e.g.  www.yahoo.com will resolve the hostname to IP
but there will be no progress and it will time out and die.
this seems too strongly suggest that the gateway which 
is the hotspot itself is not allowing internet access.
```

**Question**  
--Why does my `hotspot` only on a specific phone keep denying internet access  ( unless of course the issue is at the  client aka laptop end but seems that's not the case )

--How can I do equivalent of "reset network setting" using  `adb`   and then  avoid reboot ( delete part of `dalvik` or `/cache` ? if so which specific files / folders )

Comment: Your analogy is a bit outdated. Nowadays Microsoft embraces Linux, you even can run Linux software on any Windows 10+ machine via WSL. And for your table, sorry I don't understand it. What is "Puppy"? And what are the columns/rows should tell me?

Comment: thanks for helping me e correct thst MS stereotype.... that was just on the lighter side I am aware think that changed with MS  (  but that was its business model once upon a time which made it king    ) ...... amended question to make it easier to understand

Comment: puppy refers to the puppy Linux partition on the laptop
    so e.g. PL.Puppy  ❌   H1 means puppy Linux on PL aka 
    problem laptop does not have internet connection via 
    hotspot h1